# Patch binary with "perl -pi -e" doesn't work as expected in mac os mojave

Tags: perl, hex, patch

I want to patch a binary file with perl. The command doesn't work today, but in the past I used it a lot .

The command below doesn't work on Mac Os X:

```
perl -pi -e 's|\xA0\x37\x96\x30\xDE\x90|\xA7\x70\x92\x30\xD5\x9B|' /file.bin
```

If I use

```
perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e 's|\xA0\x37\x96\x30\xDE\x90|\xA7\x70\x92\x30\xD5\x9B|' /file.bin
```

the result is:

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\xA0\x37\x96\x30\xDE\x90/\247p\2220\325\233/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Why the replace section was modified like this?

I checked 1000 time the syntax is correct; why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: *"the command doesn't work today"* how do you know it does not work? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't modified.

```perl
"\xA7\x70\x92\x30\xD5\x9B"
```

and

```perl
"\247p\2220\325\233"
```

are equivalent.

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say "\xA7\x70\x92\x30\xD5\x9B" eq "\247p\2220\325\233" ? "same" : "diff"'
same
```

- 247<sub>8</sub> = A7<sub>16</sub>
- `p`'s ASCII encoding is 70<sub>16</sub>
- 222<sub>8</sub> = 92<sub>16</sub>
- `0`'s ASCII encoding is 30<sub>16</sub>
- 325<sub>8</sub> = D5<sub>16</sub>
- 233<sub>8</sub> = 9B<sub>16</sub>